# Argue for that the sum function $F$ for a power series satifies that $F(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{2x}{(2-x)^2}$ when $-1<x<1$

Tags: power-series

Consider the power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(1-2^{-n})z^n
$$
Then I have to argue for that the sum function $F$ for the given power series satifies that
$$
F(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{2x}{(2-x)^2}
$$
when $-1<x<1$. To be honest I have no idea how to even start this question. I have looked in my book if I could find any sentence that would help me further but I couldn't. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(1-2^{-n})z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^n=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^{n-1}=z \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n} \right)'$$

Comment: How does this relate to my question? I can't really see the connection? But the steps make sense.

Comment: @Mathias. This is exactly the answer. Finish the calculations.

Comment: So $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^n = \frac{z}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{n-1} = \frac{z}{2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^n \right)'$$ but I still dont see the connection?`